# how to put the ZTE ZXHN F660 in bridged mode

Tags: networking, router

my ISP gave me a ZTE ZXHN F660 modem/router.  from the documentation I am able to find (very little) on ZTE website it supports bridged mode.  But I can't find it anywhere in the admin pages.  Does anyone know how to get this into bridged mode?

Basically I have another router I want to use (apple airport base station) and the signal on it tends to be much better.  But the airport doesn't like it connected into another router (double NAT).  I switched the airport to bridge mode but devices take forever to connect and it (ZTE) will only gives out 1 IP address through apple bridge mode.

So I scraped the bridged mode on the airport, I disabled as much as I can on the ZTE (DHCP, WIFI) and enabled DMZ for the airport.  The airport works but has a flashing yellow light which should be green.  It just irritates me and if the ZTE could operate in bridged mode it would correct the whole thing.

Comment: It is possible your ISP has installed custom firmware on the modem which does not support bridged mode. Please speak to your ISP.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you managed to solve your problem. I can confirm that it **DOES** work in bridged mode just fine. What user/password are you logging in with? You might try the following:

```
user: admin
pass: Ql52jP23 (the second character is a lowercase letter L)
```

Works with the web access as well as with telnet (at least with the F660s in my country, your ISP could have different usr/pwd settings).

I don't think your ISP will be overly happy with you changing the settings though. Just be sure to backup them up, and to document whatever changes you make.

Cheers and HTH

Comment: You mind actually explaining how did you enable the bridge mode? Where exactly, in the web interface or via telnet? And what option, etc.

Answer (score -1):

user n password was incorrect, i think it depends where you live (country), if you live in Indonesia try this (connect via Telnet)  :
1. user : root
2. Pass : Zte521 (case sensitive)

and by this even there is **NO OPTION** to set bridge mode on your router, you have to contact your local ISP to change to bridge mode